# expo assets is not showing up in Android build version sdk 49

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am developing a small react native app using the expo framework, with SDK version 49. All icons and images are showing in expo client while developing but after building the project (with `eas build` in development or production) the icons and images vanish. Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "mobile-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/mulish": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo-google-fonts/roboto": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "expo": "~49.0.22",
    "expo-blur": "~12.4.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-contacts": "~12.2.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.12",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.5",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-localization": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
    "expo-router": "^2.0.14",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "i18n-js": "^4.3.2",
    "metro": "^0.76.7",
    "metro-config": "^0.76.7",
    "native-base": "^3.4.28",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "uuid": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "workspaces": {
    "nohoist": [
      "uuid"
    ]
  },
  "private": true,
  "resolutions": {
    "react-refresh": "~0.14.0"
  }
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

PS: I am using a monorepo

Comment: When you're running your app in development mode using expo start, Expo serves the assets from the local machine. However, when you build your app for production using eas build, Expo bundles the assets into the app package.you need to ensure that your assets are correctly referenced in your code

Comment: How do I correctly reference it? I reference it in the `app.json` file as `"assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"]`. Is that not correct?